# Ошибка чтения XML

Tags: c#, xml

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
        String xmlString = "https://oborot.in/novaposhta/city.xml";
        String xmlString2 = "https://oborot.in/novaposhta/area.xml";
        XDocument xDoc = new XDocument();
        //XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(new StringReader(xmlString));
        xDoc = XDocument.Parse(xmlString2);
        XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader(xmlString);
```

Использовал и LOAD просто с передачей строки, не загружается. Прошу помощи

Comment: вам же вроде пишут, что xml неправильный

Comment: Он правильный, от серьезной конторы взят, в которой за такое программиста не будет через час после такой ошибки

Comment: да, глянул уже. вроде в порядке

Comment: `XDocument.Parse` принимает тело xml, а не путь к нему.

Comment: @Андрей так может ответом?

Comment: @tym32167, может, но если чуть позже (если раньше никто не ответит)

Answer (score 3):

Метод `XDocument.Parse` создает новый `XDocument` из строки, и принимает на вход текст xml, а не путь к нему. Пройдите по ссылке, сохраните текст xml в string, ну а дальше разбирайте.

Answer (score 2):

```
        XDocument xDoc = new XDocument();          
        xDoc = XDocument.Load(xmlString2);
```

Все заработало